# sorting lists in python effectively

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of lists in this form and I would like to sort it based on the values (1.0, 2.0,3.0 etc). Are there any python modules that can be used?

```
class_list= [['Image_3', '3.0'], ['Image_7', '7.0'], ['Image_4', '4.0'],
             ['Image_8', '8.0'], ['Image_1', '1.0'], ['Image_5', '5.0'],
             ['Image_6', '6.0'], ['Image_2', '2.0']]
```

Comment: Did you look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)? There even is a [beginners' tutorial on sorting](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below

```
>>> class_list= [['Image_3', '3.0'], ['Image_7', '7.0'], ['Image_4', '4.0'],
             ['Image_8', '8.0'], ['Image_1', '1.0'], ['Image_5', '5.0'],
             ['Image_6', '6.0'], ['Image_2', '2.0']]
>>> sorted(class_list, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
[['Image_1', '1.0'], ['Image_2', '2.0'], ['Image_3', '3.0'], ['Image_4', '4.0'], ['Image_5', '5.0'], ['Image_6', '6.0'], ['Image_7', '7.0'], ['Image_8', '8.0']]
```

You need to convert the data type of the second value to float while sorting or otherwise it would do a string sort not a numeric sort.